# Entity Framework not sure how to retrieve Guid from one table to use in another

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework to create my database.  I have a table called "Departments" that seed first and then add two users.  I need to use the Id from the department table to seed the user table.

```
context.Department.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
    new Department() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "System", ImageNameLight = "", ImageNameDark = "" },
    new Department() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Estimating", ImageNameLight = "", ImageNameDark = "" },
    new Department() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Assembly", ImageNameLight = "dep-assy-off", ImageNameDark = "dep-assy-on" },
    new Department() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Project Engineering", ImageNameLight = "dep-pe-off", ImageNameDark = "dep-pe-on" },
);

var firstOrDefault = context.Department.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "System");
if (firstOrDefault != null)
{
    var user = new ApplicationUser
    {
        UserName = "sysadmin",
        Email = "sysadmin@noemail.com",
        EmailConfirmed = true,
        FirstName = "System",
        LastName = "Admin",
        RoleId = adminRole.Id,
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
        DepartmentId = firstOrDefault.Id
    };
```

This is what I have so far but  it does not work because the user is never created.

Comment: You need to persist the `Departments` with `context.SaveChanges()`, or populate `firstOrDefault` with `context.Department.Local.FirstOrDefault(etc)`.

Comment: the context.SaveChanges() worked ... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save to your context first or else the seed will never work try this :

```
context.Department.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
new Department() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "System", ImageNameLight = "", ImageNameDark = "" },
new Department() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Estimating", ImageNameLight = "", ImageNameDark = "" },
new Department() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Assembly", ImageNameLight = "dep-assy-off", ImageNameDark = "dep-assy-on" },
new Department() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Project Engineering", ImageNameLight = "dep-pe-off", ImageNameDark = "dep-pe-on" },
);

context.SaveChanges();
//Do whatever with your new context
```